# Dispaly Backend data using AngularJS in Java web Application

Tags: java, angularjs

How to display Backend data using AngularJS in Java web Application.
Do I need to use RESTfull Web Services.
If I don't want to use RESTfull web services, then how should I proceed.
(In my java web application m using Spring and Hibernate.)

Comment: is there a reason why you don't want to use REST? Spring has good support for REST.

Comment: This is independent of RESTification of project

Comment: @SleimanJneidi:I just want to know the alternate way. There is no specific reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS is a framework used to develop single page web applications which doesn't need refreshing and will act like a mobile application.

For this purpose, all the data required by the front end needs to come from some sort of a backend API. REST is widely used for this purpose in many leading high scale websites like twitter/facebook etc.

You should develop your Java Web Application as an API without no/less HTML pages and use that in your AngularJS front end.

Comment: Ok Thanks,ur suggestion is much needed one.

Answer (score 0):

RESTfull web services provide and easy way to integrate your AngularJS frond end with database. It is the most popular one. But it is not the only one.
You can also achieve this via different techniques.

All you need is to make call to a server technology that returns a JSON object.
That particular server technology (even a simple JSP/Servlet) can interact with database and return the expected data in JSON format.

[This link](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/backend-data/) provides a simple example to help you begin with.